# Why im not receiving the data in nodejs server using xmlhttprequest "POST"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, xmlhttprequest

im sending a data from ajax.js using XMLHttpRequest "POST" to the backend server.js , everything is OK , except that the received is UNDEFINED , and when i "console.log" it using "req.body" im expecting to see it like that "{name: 'MrSalsa'}" , but unfortunately its printed like that "[Object: null prototype] { MrSalsa: '' }"

this is the ajax.js in frontend :

```
document.getElementById('btnPost').addEventListener('click', 
function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = document.getElementById('input').value;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('post', '/api', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function(){
    if(this.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('text').innerText = this.responseText;
    }else if(this.status == 403){
      document.getElementById('text').innerText = this.responseText;
    }else if(this.status == 404){
      document.getElementById('text').innerText = this.responseText;
 }
 }
  xhr.send(data);
})
```

and this is the backend server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5050;

var users = require('./views/resources/users')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('home');
})
app.get('/api', (req,res)=>{
  res.json(users);
})
//the problem is bellow in the "POST" handler
app.post('/api', urlencodedParser, (req,res)=>{
   console.log(req.body);
res.send('welcome '+req.body.name);
})

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running on PORT : ${PORT}`));
```

and this is the form in the HTML file:

```
<form>
  <input id="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="text 
  here.." required>
  <button id="btnPost" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

and when i console.log it this is the result:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on PORT : 5050
[Object: null prototype] { MrSalsa: '' }
```

i tried to make an object in the fronend like that:

```
xhr.send({name: data});
```

but when i console.log it this is the result:

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on PORT : 5050
[Object: null prototype] { '[object Object]': '' }
```

Did i miss understood/miss somethig ? Ty For Help :)

Comment: since the server expects form data, you should send [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) ... e.g. `xhr.send(new FormData(form))` - where `form` is your form ...

Comment: `xhr.send(new FormData(this.form))` will probably work with your code

Comment: try it and this is what i get

Comment: `[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on PORT : 5050
[Object: null prototype] {
  '------WebKitFormBoundaryMEaPRIXLKCdBU4Z6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"name"\r\n\r\nMr_Salsa\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMEaPRIXLKCdBU4Z6--\r\n'
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like previous comments have stated, you set the content type as `x-www-form- 
urlencoded`, so you should pass the data as FormData.  If I were you, I would simply change the content type to `application/json`. That should fix your problem

Comment: didn't worked both for `application/json` and for `x-form-urlecoded`

Comment: this is what im getting now `[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on PORT : 5050
[Object: null prototype] {
  '------WebKitFormBoundaryMEaPRIXLKCdBU4Z6\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"name"\r\n\r\nMr_Salsa\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryMEaPRIXLKCdBU4Z6--\r\n'
}
`

Comment: `If I were you, I would simply change the content type to application/json` - that would require changes to the **server** code as well

Comment: i used `application/json` and add this `app.use(bodyParser.json())` in server.js file fixed the probelm thank you !